# Replacing transform: translate()

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need to modify my Css. 
This is my CSS

```
.msg {
    background-color: #fff;
    border: 3px solid #fff;
    display: inline-block;
    left: 50%;
color:#123456;
    opacity: 0;
    padding: 35px;
    position: fixed;
    text-align: justify;
    top: 40%;
    visibility: hidden;
    z-index: 10;

    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -moz-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -o-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

How do I remove the below section and still achieve the same result?

```
-webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
-moz-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
-ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
-o-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
```

Comment: Why do you need to remove the transform code? What functionality breaks when you remove it yourself?

Comment: That section is causing the text in .msg to look blured. When I tried removing this section the text was normal.

Comment: Since the element is positioned as `fixed`, the only way is specifying explicit `height` and `width` and use negative margins on each side to keep the element at the middle of the page.

Comment: Is it possible for you to define height of `.msg` ? If yes then I may have a solution.

Comment: #@Lokesh Suthar: hight depends on the content on .msg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can define a specific height for `.msg` this might work.

```
.msg {
    background-color: #fff;
    border: 3px solid #fff;
    display: inline-block;
    height:200px; /*If you can define this*/
    width:200px; /*and this*/
    top:calc(40% - 100px); /*then use calc() to subtract half of .msg from top*/
    left:calc(50% - 100px); /*then use calc() to subtract half of .msg from  top*/                   
    color:#123456;
    opacity: 0;
    padding: 35px;
    position: fixed;
    text-align: justify;
    visibility: hidden;
    z-index: 10;
}
```

Comment: I used only the width and left.calc - it worked perfectly... Thanks.

Comment: @LiyanaNatalie No need to use CSS3 `calc()` function (as it doesn't work with IE8-). As I noted, you can use negative margin as `margin-top: -100px; margin-left: -100px;`.